# Upper manager wants to meet informally to discuss employment possibilities

Tags: interviewing, manager

I want to get a job at a prestigious company. I recently discovered that a friend of a friend is a top manager there with lots of power and responsibility, i.e. he has the last word in deciding whether to hire or fire employees in his own department. Also, he could of course recommend someone to get into an other department.

I sent this guy a mail stating clearly my intent: i.e. whether he could help me getting a job at that company. My background is of course related and I have full confidence I can do the job. A couple of weeks later I got a reply where he said he is very eager to meet me in the weekend in an informal setting where he would like to discuss the possibilities with me.

How should I behave and what kind of things should I ask? I have never had this luxury before so you can imagine I am a bit anxious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a manager, he is always on the lookout for good, talented people. He wants to talk with you to get to know you and determine whether you're worth recommending to other managers, or even for his own organization.

Basically, if you have ever been taken out to lunch during an interview process, this meeting will be just like that. You should act as you would in a regular job interview, though you may be able to dress less formally, and the discussion may be a little more conversational. I would still avoid being too casual (no "frat chat"). Use the opportunity to ask about the environment inside the company, the projects they currently are working on, projects they are currently incubating, challenges they are facing, and others they have already overcome. Ask about his experiences at the company and what he enjoys about it.

Have a copy of your resume handy, in case he asks for one (a cover letter would also be appropriate, since he will be handing it to HR or other managers).

It's a great opportunity. The only thing you could do to ruin it would be to take it too casually, or to be too chummy. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for editing my post. I will see how the conversation will go, and if appropriate will give him my resume and cover letter.

Answer (score 3):

Everyone is different, so we can not tell you what he expects to hear. However, as "a friend of a friend", the friend you know him through should be able to help you. Ask your friend what kind of guy he is, what qualities he is looking for in people, how to behave and what to avoid.